# How to wrap lines in PDF using fpdf?

Tags: php, pdf

This is My Php Code and I am using fpdf

```
<?php

require('\lib\fpdf.php');
class PDF extends FPDF
{



//Page header
function Header()
{
//Logo
$this->Image('bis.png',10,20,33);

}

//Page footer
function Footer()
{
//Position at 1.5 cm from bottom
$this->SetY(-15);
//Arial italic 8
$this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
//Page number
$this->Cell(0,10,'Page '.$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C');
}
}


$pdf = new PDF();

$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->AliasNbPages();   
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(false);

// document properties
$pdf->SetAuthor('Karthik');
$pdf->SetTitle('PDF');
$pdf->SetXY(45,0);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',14);
$pdf->Cell(100,50,'PROJECT X');

$pdf->SetXY(45,0);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
$pdf->Cell(0,60,"Office Address:");

$pdf->SetXY(45,0);
$pdf->SetFont('Courier','',10);
$pdf->Cell(0,70,"North Sydney");
$pdf->SetXY(45,0);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
$pdf->Cell(0,80,"Ground Floor, 71 Walker Street");
$pdf->SetXY(45,0);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
$pdf->Cell(0,90,"North Sydney NSW 2060.");


//Table Heading
$pdf->SetXY(10,0);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',14);
$pdf->Cell(0,130,"Invoice");

// Add date report ran
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','I',10);
$date = date("F j, Y");
$pdf->SetXY(142,10);
$pdf->Cell(60,30,'Date: ' .$date);

$pdf->SetDrawColor(0, 0, 0); //black

//table header
$pdf->SetFillColor(170, 170, 170); //gray
$pdf->setFont("Arial","B","9");
$pdf->setXY(10, 70);

$pdf->Cell(10, 10, "id", 1, 0, "L", 1);   // CHANGE THESE TO REPRESENT YOUR 
FIELDS
$pdf->Cell(30, 10, "Date", 1, 0, "L", 1);
  // $pdf -> SetY(5);
 $pdf->Cell(60, 10, "Name", 1, 0, "L", 1);

$pdf->Cell(30, 10, "Item", 1, 0, "L", 1);
$pdf->Cell(20, 10, "GST", 1, 0, "L", 1);
$pdf->Cell(25, 10, "Price", 1, 0, "L", 1);



//Data Access From The Database
$x = 10;
$y = 80;


$pdf->setXY($x, $y);

$pdf->setFont("Arial","","9");


include('api/db_config.php');


$query_result = "SELECT * FROM projectx"; 
$result = mysql_query($query_result, $conOpen) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{


    $pdf->Cell(10, 8, $row['id'], 1);   // CHANGE THESE TO REPRESENT YOUR 
  FIELDS
    $pdf->Cell(30, 8, $row['date'], 1);



    $pdf->MultiCell(60, 8, $row['Name'], 1);
    $pdf->Cell(30, 8, $row['Item'], 1);
    $pdf->Cell(20, 8, $row['GST'], 1);
    $pdf->Cell(25, 8, $row['Price'], 1);
    // header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
    // header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=download.pdf');

    $y += 8;



    if ($y > 260)    // When you need a page break
    {
        $pdf->AddPage();
        $y = 40;

    }

    $pdf->setXY($x, $y);

   }



   $pdf->SetXY(150,100);
   $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
   $pdf->Cell(0,90,"TOTAL");

   $pdf->SetXY(165,100);
   $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
   $pdf->Cell(0,90,"$ 88");

 $pdf->Output();
```

This is My PDF Image

[image]

Here I am using fpdf for generating pdf file and I have 5 columns and If the name column contains more character then the sentence not fit in the row that should print in the next line for that reason I am Using MultiCell after using that other columns are also coming one step down as shown in the image. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to start with an actual question. Format your question like "This is my question. Here is what I tried so far." instead of "This is my code, what's wrong with it?". Please see [ask] for more information.

Comment: He took your suggestion far too literally.